# Get name of image from function parameter

Tags: javascript, html

I need to embed an image to an element. For instance, in the below code, the image `dog.png` will be inserted to `#board` div. How can I do it?

### HTML

```
<div id="board"></div>
```

#### JavaScript

```
function show_image(symbol, value, identificator) {
    var img = document.createElement("IMG");
    img.src = symbol.png;
    identificator.appendChild(img);
}

show_image("dog", "15", "board");
```

Comment: What's the `15` for?

Comment: does `document.getElementById(indentificator).appendChild(img)` do what you want?

Comment: Are you trying to concatenate the string value in `symbol` with ".png"?

Comment: @JackBashford It does not matter.

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ Yeah, but I have problem with Jack's solution.

Comment: @DaveStSomeWhere Now yes.

Comment: What happens when you try Jack's solution?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `getElementById` and `appendChild`. Also note you needed to concatenate the `.png` string - you were trying to access `"dog".png` which doesn't exist:

```js
function show_image(symbol, value, identificator) {
  var img = document.createElement("IMG");
  img.src = symbol + ".png";
  document.getElementById(identificator).appendChild(img);
}

show_image("dog", "15", "board");
```

```html
<div id="board"></div>
```

Comment: It's weird. It does not work for me. I have bell.png in the same folder and I tested insert text to `document.getElementById(identificator)` (it worked).